# In a bare repository, is it safe to push (to another repos) while pushes are being done (to that repo)?

Tags: git

In a bare repository, is it safe to push (to another repos) while pushes are being done (to that repo)?

Reason I am asking this is that in a project I worked on I saw a weird git replication schema: in the post-receive hook of the main repo (that repo is bare), the replicas are asked (in background) to do a `git fetch`.  Replicas are bare repositories also.  I was told that if the post receive hook just initiated a `git push` in background the references in the replicas ended with the wrong values if users kept pushing to the main repo in the meanwhile.

Since I want to setup a replica schema for another project, I was wondering about the reason behind the push schema failing (I need little replication lag, but I don't want post-receive hook taking too long, as it would do with synchronous pushes to all replicas).

Is any local data (I am thinking `objects/pack/*` or `packed-refs`) modified while receiving data and used while pushing?  I cannot think of other reasons

Answer (score -2):

first of all check your remote

> git remote -v

then check the repo is same as your repo or not
if not remove it

> git remove upstream

then set your upstream

> git set upstream 
>   then is worked fine you will be able to push and pull

Comment: I can push/pull with no problem.  I am worried about race conditions, though.